# overflow error in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I wrote this function to map date to time.

```
df1=pd.read_csv("database.csv")

def mapdateTotime(x):
    try:
        return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x,
"%m/%d/%Y").timetuple())

    except ValueError:
        return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").timetuple())

df1.Date = df1.Date.apply(mapdateTotime)
```

the database.csv file contains some dates and time values and I need to map them.
But I am getting this overflow error. How do I solve it.

the error is:

```
    OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-05c73c6f7120> in <module>()
      8     except ValueError:
      9         return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").timetuple())
---> 10 df1.Date = df1.Date.apply(mapdateTotime)

c:\users\amol\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2353             else:
   2354                 values = self.asobject
-> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2356 
   2357         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66645)()

<ipython-input-6-05c73c6f7120> in mapdateTotime(x)
      5 def mapdateTotime(x):
      6     try:
----> 7         return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y").timetuple())
      8     except ValueError:
      9         return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").timetuple())

OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```